# Holy as the elements

Tags: riddle, word

```
Everybody should be able to solve this one!
```

You might try to pet me or kick my butt
but you can not touch me no matter what
If you gave me presents I'd leave you for sure
but take what's around me and I will endure
You can search the whole ocean or even beyond
in sometimes for sure, a loch or a pond
If you see what's behind it
you are very close
And as you assumed
its right under your nose
Additional verses

> are not available for this is a really easy one!

Since it is an easy one I want every single line ripped apart!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you:

> A HOLE

?

You might try to pet me or kick my butt
but you can not touch me no matter what

> You can caress the abyss or kick it but you will never make contact. "No matter" may be a clue here. There are some more graphic and direct applications of petting and kicking with regards to a HOLE, but never mind.

If you gave me presents I'd leave you for sure

> If one fills a hole it is no longer a hole

but take what's around me and I will endure

> You can make a hole bigger and it is still a hole

You can search the whole ocean or even beyond
in sometimes for sure, a loch or a pond

> Very clever. "Whole"=HOLE. "Loch" = HOLE (in German). Also note the presence of "O" in all the key words.

If you see whats behind it
you are very close

> If you can see the bottom of the hole, you must be close to it (or even in it).

And as you assumed
its right under your nose

> Your mouth is a HOLE of sorts :O

Comment: Sounds like it could fit! Was having a bit of a hard time seeing how it fits in with `If you see whats behind it` but guess the 'nothing' here could be the space before the word 'it'.

Comment: @DavieBrown Yeah, I'm still working on some details. I was thinking that you can always see behind nothing... so maybe that resolves it

Comment: The more I think of this, the more I realize you're (I hope) correct!  I've spent the best part of an hour looking at this now.

Comment: I will be picky on this one. Let the cops deal with the water.

Comment: @DavieBrown Only an hour :O Well, you got away easy if it's right

Comment: @avigrail So, it's right but you want a better explanation for the water clue? if so, I will stay up all night if I have to :p

Comment: I put a lot of time in some undiscovered details. Plus, the word "nothing" is not wrong, technically. But a more geometrical name could reveal some mysteries in this riddle.

Comment: @avigrail All right, let me consider this problem further. Your puzzles sind ausgezeichnet :D

Comment: That's my boy! Danke ;)

Comment: @avigrail I'm still trying... I have made some small mods

Comment: You will find some nice things by going in this direction.

Comment: Tell me if you want the full solution and we can open up a chat. For now I'm almost satisfied and you seem to become the dah-ditty-dah that solves it!

Comment: @avigrail Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18625/discussion-between-dalarcop-and-avigrail).

Comment: The letter 'O' is a 'hole' of sorts, and is present in all the words in the funkily constructed third stanza.

Comment: @KenoguLabz Yep, look at one of the edits - I made the exact same point. Then look at the chat :p

Answer (score 3):

> Bacteria
>  you cant touch them
>  present as in medicine
>  it feeds of whats around it such as a host
>  they survive underwater
>  you look through them so youd be close looking anywhere
>  they are in and around your nose.

Comment: That's a nice solution, however, not the correct one here.

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's definetely an interesting riddle. My try will be:

> space (maybe empty space)

or

> air

Comment: I like this one a lot. Space makes more sense than air, though, with the water part.

Comment: I can't comment your solution for mysterious reasons. But I will get back to you as soon as the riddle will be solved!

Comment: I encourage you to try again for there are some new opinions on the market that will support you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm stumped with a few of these lines, they're always excluding some ideas I have.

> But my best shot is a "riddle".

You might try to pet me or kick my butt

> Implies liking it, and / or trying to solve it

but you can not touch me no matter what

> A concept

If you gave me presents I'd leave you for sure

> Answer me and I'm done

but take what's around me and I will endure

> I'll keep nagging your brain if you give me false answers

You can search the whole ocean or even beyond
in sometimes for sure, a loch or a pond

> Not sure how this could fit though.

If you see whats behind it you are very close

> Seeing the tricks / word plays for what they are

And as you assumed its right under your nose

> I have a riddle in front of me

Comment: "but take what's around me and I will endure" - maybe removing letters from the sides leaves 'i'... r**i**ddle

Comment: Wow! That's what I'd call a very good attempt (although it's wrong).

Answer (score 3):

> Kim Kardashian

You might try to pet me or kick my butt
but you can not touch me no matter what

> She's pretty much unavailable

If you gave me presents I'd leave you for sure
but take what's around me and I will endure

> She's not into nice guys

You can search the whole ocean or even beyond
in sometimes for sure, a loch or a pond

> She looks good in a bikini (near bodies of water)

If you see whats behind it

> Giggity

you are very close
And as you assumed
its right under your nose

> She shows up everywhere; the media love her for some reason